# Using for if in Excel VBA to count cells value until last row but at the same time want to make it less than 30

Tags: excel, loops, vba

As an example:

```
For i = 1 To LastRow
   If Cells(i, 1).Value = "Tube1" Then
       Val1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value
       Val2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2).Value
```

I want the code to find the word "tube" in all the cell in Excel sheet but it can only be until 30.Assume that the keyword here is "Tube". The path name can be changed from Tube1, Tube2, Tube3 etc but it can only be until Tube30. which mean it can only count the word "tube" for 30 times. Every path contains the different value after a cell behind it, example; (Tube1, value). How to get the value part settles down and the prob that I have right now is how to make sure that the code count the path not to become more than 30.

Comment: If you want the code to find the word `Path` then why do you have the word `Tube1` in your code sample above? What do you mean by "make it less than 30"? What should be less than 30? The string can certainly not be more than 30 because the string you are looking for is only 4 letters long `path`. If you want to exit the loop before getting to 30 then you should keep track of the occurrences with another variable (which I don't see in the above code). You might be able to help us understand with some sample data and the desired outcome attached to the post.

Comment: sorry, it's a typo there i didn't notice it. well, honestly i don't even know how should I explain this. kinda clueless rn. i want to find the word "Tube1" instead of Path. less than 30 here means that i want the code to detect only 30 words of the word "tube" here. For i = 1 To LastRow means to check the word "tube" until the last row but the tube can only be until 30,"tube30". i can't use for i = 1 To 30 because the word "Tube" can be changed (Tube1) and can be in different places in the excel sheets. sorry but the "strings" that you mean there doesn't even relate to the question actually

Comment: the keyword here is "tube" and i want it to be less than 30. the tube name can be from Tube1,Tube2 until Tube30 or Tube 60 but the code can only detect the name "tube" that only repeats 30 times

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% what you're asking but I think this will be a pointer for you

Using `Instr` you can find only cells which contain the substring of "Path". We'll then do a bit of string manipulation to test whether the number in the cell value is equal to or less than 30. If not we'll `Exit` the `for` loop.

I think this should point you in the right direction of what you want

```
For i = 1 To LastRow
   If Instr(1, Cells(i, 1).Value2, "Path", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
       If CInt(Replace(Cells(i, 1).Value2, "Path", vbnullstring)) <= 30 then Exit For

       Val1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value2
       Val2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2).Value2
   End If
Next i
```

Comment: thank you, tom! I think you get what I'm trying to ask here. this is a clue for me. i will try to do put this things in my code